# PHP, JS View Counter and Save

Tags: javascript, html, css, file, local-storage

I try to make a view counter in js for my webpage.

When you view the page, the counter will increase with 1.

The counted numbers are displayed.

But one thing is not working: When I view the website from another device, the counter starts at 0.

So I used localStorage to store the data. But I want when I see the page from my laptop, the counter increases by one.  And when I view the page from my phone the counter should already show the number one and should increase it with one ,so the counter will be 2.

I don't know how to make it workable. It's only done with LocalStorage. I thought I should save the data, by storing the data in a .txt file, but it does not work because when the filewriter save the datas (1) into the file, it will save the next view (1) next to the previous number. And if I want to add the current number to the previous it will show number 1.

Here's my code:

```js
var n = localStorage.getItem('profile_1_tech.html');

if (n === null) {
  n = 0;
}

n++;

localStorage.setItem("profile_1_tech.html", n);

document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = n;
```

```html
<span><span id="counter"></span> Views</span>
```

So I need to result be added (1 view + 1 view for each view), and all the user can see the same number.

Comment: If you want to make a counter that is shared between devices, you need to store that information somewhere where all devices can access it, like a server. You can't achieve this solely with client-side JavaScript.

Comment: To expand on @Ivar's comment, the reason this is the case is because the variables assigned on client-side JavaScript reset every time the browser is loaded even on the same device. A server would allow you to make an API call, or connect to a `websocket` (for real-time updates), or whatever method you want to use to access the counter, which would be stored on the server and updated in the server.

Comment: So I am not be able to use websocket on localhost?

Comment: If you load the page on both devices from localHost, it can work if you update the file and read the file before showing. You need to ajax the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaScript `LocalStorage` API is only meant to be used on one device, and using the `SessionStorage` API would be of even less use because that memory is cleared as soon as the tab is closed.

As your question tag has `PHP` included what you can do is create an account system that increments a value that you would store in a SQL table using PHP, and every time a user creates an account you would create a new "views" field just for them.

However if you are trying to use a view counter for analytical purposes to see how many people use your website then I can suggest using Google Analytics because it is free and requires very minimal code as opposed to my aforementioned "account system" approach with storing the views in a database with PHP.